# Polylang plugin for Wordpress does not have string translation menu

Tags: wordpress, translation, multilingual, polylang

I have installed a plugin on WordPress 4.9.2. I have only three plugin menu items Languages, Settings and Lingotek, String translation option is missing. I am trying to work with some custom theme, created by the developer.

When I am selecting default language and applying it to posts, tags, etc – most part of my site is not displaying at all.

How can I fix this issue&

Comment: We need more information to help you on this issue. Basically, just try to install a fresh WP with clean and up-to-date Polylang plugin to see if the issue is still there. Then, try disabling all other plugin, one by one. Also, be sure to try to switch to a clean theme (twenty seventeen, e.g.).

Comment: Thank you,  enguerranws.I have up-to-date Polylang, already have tried a clean theme, also I have disabled all installed plugins – no change. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Did you try to test it on a fresh WP install? If you can reproduce this issue on a fresh, clean WP without any plugins, I guess you can report the bug to the Polylang team.

Comment: Yeah, I have tried, it works fine, I am looking for suggestions what can cause the problem and I have not seen any quite similar in the web